# cloudfront removes cache-control header for custom origin

Tags: caching, google-cloud-storage, amazon-cloudfront

I am using google cloud storage to store my static files. I want to use cloudfront for static content to save some network latency for users in same geographical location. But I am having trouble enabling browser side caching while using cloudfront.

When I request static files form my server, http response I get is mentioned below :

```
Alternate-Protocol:80:quic,p=0.5
Cache-Control:public, max-age=7200
Content-Length:57420
Content-Type:image/jpeg
Date:Fri, 10 Apr 2015 08:34:04 GMT
ETag:"51988d8bda68def10ccbf20be57c4e92"
Server:Google Frontend
```

But when is fetch same content from cloudfront cache-control header is removed as shown below :

```
Alternate-Protocol:80:quic,p=0.5,80:quic,p=0.5
Cache-Control:private
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:57420
Content-Type:image/jpeg
Date:Fri, 10 Apr 2015 08:34:15 GMT
ETag:"51988d8bda68def10ccbf20be57c4e92"
Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Server:Google Frontend
Via:1.1 c038088d4b94486d7346fd44d03188a0.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id:EsZLHl0_FzO-naSjD8umC90_nxLXj-LzpHWQYoT6_3hIsKS3TqfOnw==
X-Cache:Miss from cloudfront
```

What am I doing wrong?

ps. I haven't set file's metadata in google cloud storage and adding 'etag' and 'cache-control' headers in httpservletresponse ( java backend ) at run time.

Thanx!

Comment: I don't think CloudFront will preserve Cache-Control from the source, you need to set it explicitly as per http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html

Comment: I see you get Miss from CloudFront. Can you try to do the same request two times in a row, would you get a Hit? If not, it means that CloudFront receives Cache-Control: private from origin, and does not cache object at all.